# Displaying estimated upload time to upload a folder in Amazon S3 bucket on my PHP webpage

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a webpage which lets the users to upload files and folders to the Amazon S3 bucket. Users can also have access to those data via the webpage. The webpage is built on PHP. The loading page while uploading data displays the percentage of data that had been uploaded in real time. Everything that I have said, works fine so far.

Now, we need an additional feature, where in the loading page of data upload, along with the uploaded-percentage information, we need to display the estimated amount of time remaining to fully upload the contents to the S3 bucket. Just like the one that appears while downloading something from the internet, or copying something from the computer to your external hard disk. Is there any way to do that? I can't find a way on the internet as far as I have searched.

I recently started learning web development and it's been a couple of weeks since I joined this live project.

Comment: [upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931959/detect-how-long-it-takes-for-a-file-to-upload-php) or [download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598765/file-download-time-in-php-mysql) ..

Answer (score 0):

You have the percentage (progress) of the upload. Given you remember the start time of the upload, you can interpolate (estimate) the total time needed using the current time.

First remember the start date/time of the upload:

```js
const start = Date.now();
```

Then at any given time:

```js
currentPercent = ...; // <-- you have this available for example in every tick when the percent changes
const millisecondsSinceStart = Date.now() - start;
const totalTimeNeededInMilliseconds = millisecondsSinceStart/currentPercent*100;
const stillRemainingTimeInMilliseconds = totalTimeNeededInMilliseconds - millisecondsSinceStart;
```

Note: I have assumed you want this estimation indication on the frontend, so I wrote JS code, but consider it pseudocode - if you wish.